# Button id as an event handler

Tags: c#, button, webforms

I am creating 7 buttons on the fly

when i create the buttons i am trying to have an event handler than can deal with all clicks in one method via a switch. Ideally i want to pass an id with the button that indicates what was clicked, opposed to this solution of

```
void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    Console.WriteLine(b.Text);
}
```

as all of the buttons using this event handler have the same text. I have a unique id associated witht the buttons but no idea how to send them

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Name` or `Tag` properties.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ID in the Tag property on the button when you create them and then check the ID in your event handler.

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Tag = 1;

...

void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    switch ((int)b.Tag)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Bad practice to handle several clicks in one event via switch. But however a solution would be:

Create your own control which inherits the button and ad your ID as an property. So you can access it via:

```
MyButton b = (MyButton)sender;

switch(b.ID) { 
    //Code goes here 
}
```

Comment: the thing is every button does the same thing, it loads a byte array, based on the value passed. Surely its only bad practise if you need bespoke handling events?

Answer (score 0):

If each button you add has a unique Id, why not just use the ID property of the button?

```
Button button = new Button();
button.ID= "Button1";

//...

void pdfButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    switch(button.ID)
    {
        case "Button1":
          //...
    }

}
```